# Inserting UIHostingController with changeable height into UIStackView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uistackview, uihostingcontroller

I have an issue where I'm trying to insert a SwiftUI view into an existing UIKit view. The SwiftUI view can change height dynamically, but the UIStackView does not adjust to the new size. I've created a (hideous) test project to highlight this.

Button:

```
class TestButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButton()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButton()
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupButton() {
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = .red
        titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

SwiftUI View:

```
struct TestSwiftUIView: View {
    @State var text: [String] = ["This is a line of text"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(text, id: \.self) { text in
                Text(text)
            }
            Button {
                text.append("New line")
            } label: {
                Text("Add line")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var titleLabel = UILabel()
    var stackView = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTitleLabels()
        configureStackView()
    }
    
    func configureStackView() {
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 20
        
        addButtonsToStackView()
        setStackViewConstraints()
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: TestSwiftUIView())
        stackView.insertArrangedSubview(hostingController.view, at: 3)
    }
    
    func addButtonsToStackView() {
        let numberOfButtons = 5
        
        for i in 1...numberOfButtons {
            let button = TestButton()
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }
    
    func setStackViewConstraints() {
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 30)
            .isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    }
    
    func configureTitleLabels() {
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.text = "Test project"
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        
        setTitleLabelConstaints()
    }
    
    func setTitleLabelConstaints() {
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20)
            .isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

How can we ensure that the UIStackView allows enough space for the expanding SwiftUI view?

**UPDATE**

I had an idea that I may need to do something with `layoutIfNeeded()`. So I added a callback to the button within the SwiftUI View as follows:

```
let callback: () -> Void
```

And then in the button function:

```
Button {
    text.append("New line")
    callback()
} label: {
    Text("Add line")
        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold, design: nil))
}
```

Then in ViewController:

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: TestSwiftUIView(callback: {
            self.stackView.subviews.forEach { view in
                view.sizeToFit()
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }))
```

Sadly this had no impact :(

Answer (score 11):

You're running into a couple problems... actually, several :(

---

TL;DR version:

- `UIHostingController` views don't work in the same way as `UIKit` views
- you've set the stack view to `.fillEqually`, which means the arranged subviews will **never** change size.

---

The long version:

First, when UIKit loads a `UIHostingController` view, it uses that view's `.intrinsicContentSize`. But, because of the way SwiftUI views work, that doesn't "automatically" update.

You can see this by stripping your UIKit view controller down to **only** the hosting controller:

```
class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: TestSwiftUIView())

        // let's unwrap the view to save a little typing
        guard let v = hostingController.view else { return }
        
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        
        // now let's add that view leading/trailing with 40-points on each side
        //  and vertically centered (no Height constraint)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        // let's give the view a background color
        //  so we can see its frame
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
    }
    
}
```

This is what we get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As we see, the green `vStack` expands vertically, but the yellow view doesn't change.

There are a couple ways to "fix" that...

First, you were on the right track with your `callback` approach, but let's do it like this.

We'll add a var property to hold a reference to the hosted view:

```
// so we have a reference to the hosting controller's view
var hcView: UIView!
```

and when we get the callback, we'll update it like this:

```
func updateSize() {
    hcView.setNeedsLayout()
    hcView.layoutIfNeeded()
    hcView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

Here's a modified example:

```
struct CallbackTestSwiftUIView: View {
    let callback: () -> Void
    @State var strings: [String] = [
        "This is a line of text",
    ]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { text in
                Text(text)
            }
            Button {
                strings.append("New line \(strings.count)")
                callback()
            } label: {
                Text("Add line")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

class CallbackSimpleViewController: UIViewController {

    // so we have a reference to the hosting controller's view
    var hcView: UIView!
    
    func updateSize() {
        hcView.setNeedsLayout()
        hcView.layoutIfNeeded()
        hcView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: CallbackTestSwiftUIView(callback: {
            self.updateSize()
        }))
        
        // let's unwrap the view to save a little typing
        guard let v = hostingController.view else { return }
        
        // save the view reference
        self.hcView = v
        
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        
        // now let's add that view leading/trailing with 40-points on each side
        //  and vertically centered (no Height constraint)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        // let's give the view a background color
        //  so we can see its frame
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
    }
    
}
```

and here's the output, with the yellow view growing along with the green view:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So -- woo hoo! Just implement that with your stack view layout and we're done, right?

Whoops, not quite.

You gave your stack view Top and Bottom constraints, and set its `.distribution = .fillEqually`.

So, the stack view says "I have 6 arranged subviews now, so make them all the same heights ***and never let the heights change!!!***

You *might* try `.distribution = .fillProportionally` ... unfortunately, that fails miserably when the stack view's spacing is not Zero. There are ways around that, but it might not give you the desired result anyway.

So, let's use the `CallbackTestSwiftUIView` and a slightly modified version of your original `ViewController` with the stack view and buttons:

```
class CallbackInStackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var titleLabel = UILabel()
    var stackView = UIStackView()
    
    // so we have a reference to the hosting controller's view
    var hcView: UIView!
    
    func updateSize() {
        hcView.setNeedsLayout()
        hcView.layoutIfNeeded()
        hcView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTitleLabels()
        configureStackView()
    }
    
    func configureStackView() {
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        
        // use .fill instead of .fillEqually
        //stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        
        stackView.spacing = 20

        addButtonsToStackView()
        setStackViewConstraints()
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: CallbackTestSwiftUIView(callback: {
            self.updateSize()
        }))
        
        // let's unwrap the view to save a little typing
        guard let v = hostingController.view else { return }
        
        // save the view reference
        self.hcView = v
        
        stackView.insertArrangedSubview(v, at: 3)
        
        // let's give the view a background color
        //  so we can see its frame
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
    
    func addButtonsToStackView() {
        let numberOfButtons = 5
        
        for i in 1...numberOfButtons {
            let button = TestButton()
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }
    
    func setStackViewConstraints() {
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        
        // remove stack view's bottom anchor
        //stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    }
    
    func configureTitleLabels() {
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.text = "Test project"
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        
        setTitleLabelConstaints()
    }
    
    func setTitleLabelConstaints() {
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        // don't let title label stretch vertically
        titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

    }
    
}
```

Which may or may not give you what you need:

[image]

[image]

[image]

but at least we have the sizing in the stack view working.

---

Some searching comes up with various ways to make "auto-sizing" hosting controllers ... I do very little with SwiftUI, so I can't give you a recommendation on which approach might be the best.

Comment: That's a great explanation! I've had a similar problem related to adjusting the size of UIHostingController once SwiftUI view changes its frame.

Comment: Only thing left is animating swiftui view and hostingcontroller. Together. In harmony...